# Comportamiento de ^ y $ en regex

Tags: python, regex

```
if re.search("^\d{3}$","1234"):
   print(True)
else:
   print(False)
```

Por que este codigo imprime False?La idea es que busque si un string empieza con tres digitos y termina con tres digitos. En el caso de "1234" se cumple la condicion ya que empieza con 123 y termina con 234. Como seria el codigo para esto?

Comment: Felka98, cuando dices que la cadena debe empezar y terminar con tres dígitos, quiere decir que esta cadena "123hola123" también es válida?

Answer (score 3):

Ese regex reconoce 3 digitos y nada más. Es decir que entre el inicio y el fin haya 3 dígitos.

Este regex divide el problema en 2:

```
(?:(?:^\d{3,6}$)|(?:^\d{3}.*\d{3}$))
```

Hasta 6 caracteres, todos deben ser dígitos.
A partir de los 7 se usa la segunda parte que control que los primeros 3 sean dígitos, y que los últimos 3 también lo sean. En el medio puede haber prácticamente cualquier caracter.

[Podes probarlo acá](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo a la pregunta del enunciado, como bien asumiste en tu código, el simbolo **^** es para indicar que la secuencia a continuación debe estar al principio de la cadena, mientras que lo que anteceda a **$** deberá estár al final. Ahora, al decir "^\d{3}$", estás diciendo que esperas que los **mismos** tres dígitos deben estar al principio y al final, lo cual no es válido, y es el motivo del valor False que estas recibiendo.